# Extract a single value from two arrays that share the same one in php?

Tags: php, arrays, function

```
$actresses = array(
    1 => "Natalie Wood",
    2 => "Audrey Hepburn",
    3 => "Marilyn Monroe",
    4 => "Grace Kelly",
    5 => "Olivia Hussey");

$actressestoday = array(
    6 => "Jennifer Lopez",
    7 => "Jennifer Love Hewitt",
    8 => "Paula Newman",
    9 => "Lindsay Lohan",
   10 => "Michelle Branch",
   11 => "Olivia Hussey");
```

How do I extract only Olivia Hussey from the array using a function?   Basically,  how do I combine the two columns and then output a single value for Olivia   Hussey using a function in php?

I've tried the following but it is not working:

```
 $allactresses = array_intersect($actresses, $actressestoday);
 $value = array_column($allactresses, '11');
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is find the values that match?

Comment: Maybe something like, https://eval.in/579783?

Comment: If you want the exact value: **`$result = reset(array_intersect($actresses, $actressestoday));`** will echo out `Olivia Hussey`. (*`reset()` - "rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the value of the first array element."*)

Answer (score 0):

According to the the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), the keys are from the *first" array, not the second.  So this might work:

```
$allactresses = array_intersect($actresses, $actressestoday); 
$value = $allactresses[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) is the way to go:

```
$result = reset(array_intersect($actressestoday, $actresses));
echo $result;
//Olivia Hussey
```

---

[Demo](http://ideone.com/8Jxmdr)

---

> `array_intersect()` returns an array containing all the values of array1
>   that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are preserved.

---

> `reset()` rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and
>   returns the value of the first array element.